# Trouble with Karma + AngularJS Scenario Test Runner and a form

Tags: testing, angularjs-e2e, angular-scenario

Ok, I'm having issues with my Test Runner where it is filling out the fields on the form but when I then submit the forms it refers to these fields as blank.

If I write to the field using element('some_element).val('some_val') this works fine.

If I then check the field with expect(element('some_element').val()).toBe('some_val') it passes without any problem

BUT

If I submit this form, it returns saying all these elements are empty. However I can change just one character manually and it accepts it without any issues.

Could anyone explain what would cause such an issue? And also any possible solutions on how to get round it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with KendoUI and not the test runner.